# Associative Laws

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Associative laws: $\begin{align}(p\lor q)\lor r&\equiv p\lor(q\lor r)\\(p\land q)\land r&\equiv p\land(q\land r)\end{align}$

Just curious is $(r\land p)\land q$ also the same as $(p\land q)\land r$? Like are there $3$ options here because I'm only seeing two options.

Comment: Note $\land,\,\lor$ are also commutative.

Comment: Surely you have some "Commutativity Laws"?

Comment: I mean I do also have commutative laws that say q∧p and p∧q are the same but I'm not sure how that helps prove what I'm asking to prove and I'm still kinda confused here so is what I said right?

Answer (score 1):

The identity $(r\land p)\land q = (p\land q)\land r$ holds if $\land$ is commutative and associative, but it may fail if $\land$ is commutative but not associative, as in the example below:
$$
\begin{array}{c|rrr|}
\land&p&q&r \\
\hline 
p&p&r&q \\
q&r&q&p \\
r&q&p&r \\
\hline 
\end{array}
$$
In this example, $(r\land p)\land q = q \land q = q$ but $(p\land q)\land r = r \land r = r$.

Comment: I honestly don't even understand this answer or any of them.. I don't get this truth table this isn't like any truth tables I've seen before

Comment: I mean isn't ∧ always commutative and associative? When would it not be..?

Comment: Here $\land$ is just a binary operation on the set $\{p, q, r\}$.

Comment: So it is associative right?

Comment: No, it is not associative.

Answer (score 0):

That is true if and only if it is conmutative.

Conmutation for operation ∨:
$a ∨ b=b ∨ a$

Comment: This is not true, see my answer.